# Dies for no reason

Tags: electrical

I have a 2003 Honda accord and I'll be driving at freeway speed and out of nowhere everything in the car goes dead including the engine. After a few moments I'll hit the starter and she fires up like nothing had happened. It usually only happens once a trip and for only a few moments. I've checked all I can think of and found nothing

Comment: There **is** a reason - you just have not found it yet... have you checked the grounding straps tightness, condition, corrosion?

Comment: Do you literally mean "everything"?  Lights, radio, gauges, heater, wipers, windows, horn..........?

Comment: Sounds like a fuel pump is failing.